# Where should a static const data member be defined?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, constants, static-members

I have a class

```
class foo {
public:
   foo();
   foo( int );
private:
   static const string s;
};
```

Where is the best place to initialize the string `s` in the source file?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Anywhere in **one** compilation unit (usually a .cpp file) would do:

foo.h

```
class foo {
    static const string s; // Can never be initialized here.
    static const char* cs; // Same with C strings.

    static const int i = 3; // Integral types can be initialized here (*)...
    static const int j; //     ... OR in cpp.
};
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
const string foo::s = "foo string";
const char* foo::cs = "foo C string";
// No definition for i. (*)
const int foo::j = 4;
```

(*) According to the standards you must define `i` outside of the class definition (like `j` is) if it is used in code other than just integral constant expressions. See David's comment below for details.

Comment: I have upvoted, but after reviewing the standard there is an error in your code: `i` must be *defined* in the cpp. §9.4.2/4 *If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a constant-initializer which shall be an integral constant expression (5.19). In that case, the member can appear in integral constant expressions. The member shall still be defined in a name- space scope if it is used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.*

Comment: Based on your quote from the standards, it seems `i` would have to be be defined *only* if it was used somewhere else than in integral constant expressions, right? In this case you cannot say that there is an error because there is not enough context to be sure -- or stricly speaking the above example is correct if there is no other code.

Now I do appreciate your comment (+1), I'm still learning things myself! So I'll try and clarify that point in the answer, please let me know if it's better...

Comment: @squelart Sorry if I sound dumb but an example of statement other than integral constant expression would be?

Comment: @Saksham For example calling a function, e.g.: `int f() { return 42; } class foo { static const int i = f(); /* Error! */ }` Note that C++11 allows calling 'constexpr' functions: `constexpr int f() { return 42; } class foo { static const int i = f(); /* Ok */ }`

Comment: @squelart I read the text such that the definition must be supplied if the member is used at all - the wording in the standard doesn't limit that requirement to integral constant expressions.

Comment: btw,  we can cope `const static bool` member data with the same of  `const static int`

Answer (score 25):

Since C++17 the *inline* specifier also applies to variables. You can now define static member variables in the class definition:

```
#include <string>

class foo {
public:
   foo();
   foo( int );
private:
   inline static const std::string s { "foo" };
};
```

Answer (score 13):

In a translation unit within the same namespace, usually at the top:

```
// foo.h
struct foo
{
    static const std::string s;
};

// foo.cpp
const std::string foo::s = "thingadongdong"; // this is where it lives

// bar.h
namespace baz
{
    struct bar
    {
        static const float f;
    };
}

// bar.cpp
namespace baz
{
    const float bar::f = 3.1415926535;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Static members need to be initialized in a .cpp translation unit at file scope or in the appropriate namespace:

```
const string foo::s( "my foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Only integral values (e.g., `static const int ARRAYSIZE`) are initialized in header file because they are usually used in class header to define something such as the size of an array. Non-integral values are initialized in implementation file.