# static member variable's in-class assignment

Tags: c++, static-members

Here is the code,

```
class A {
public:
    static A *get_a()
    {
        if(_pa == 0)
            _pa = new A;
        return _pa;
    }

private:
    static A *_pa = 0;  //cannot compile
};
```

In the above code, if I move `_pa`'s definition outof the class,

```
A * A::_pa = 0;  //can compile
```

My problem is, `static A *_pa = 0` inside the class body is just a declaration, not a definition, right?

Moreover, is it valid to assign a value to a `static` data member inside the class?

Comment: 1) Correct, it doesn't even work in C++11, as all that does is sub it in where it would normally be default-initialized (i.e., when an object is created). 2) Yes, static variables can be accessed through the class itself, or objects.

Comment: The first one is explained well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize a static member in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531060/how-to-initialize-a-static-member-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it's a **const** integral type (char, short, int, ...) you have to define the static member in a .cpp-File in addition to the declaration in the header.

```
header:
class XYZ {
  static XYZ * instance;
};

//cpp:
XYZ * XYZ::instance;
```