# C++ inline initialization of a static const char*

Tags: c++

Why I cannot initialize a static const char* in the header file?
In my code I have in my Class header:

```
static const char* xml_ID_TAG;
```

and in the cpp:

```
const char* Class::xml_ID_TAG = "id";
```

The xml_ID_TAG variable contains the attribute string of an XML document.
Since it's static, const, primitive type (char*), etc... I can't figure out why the compiler forbid to write something like:

```
static const char* xml_ID_TAG = "id";
```

I'm using MSVC2013 compiler, giving for the example above the error: "Error: a member with an in-class initializer must be const"

Comment: Only `static const` integral members can be defined inside a class body. This is to prevent ODR violations.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally speaking you must define your static members in precisely one translation unit, and the language helps to enforce this by prohibiting you from writing an initialiser for such a member inside the surrounding class definition:

```
struct T
{
   static int x = 42;
   // ^ error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of
   // non-const static member 'T::x'
};
```

However, a special exception is made for constants, for convenience:

```
struct T
{
   static const int x = 42;
   // ^ OK
};
```

Note that in most cases you still need to *define* the constant (in your .cpp file would be the best place):

```
const int T::x;
```

---

> `[C++11: 9.4.2/3]:]` If a non-volatile `const static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression (5.19). A `static` data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression. *[ Note:* In both these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. *—end note ]* The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is *odr-used* (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.

---

Now, your member is not an `int` and even a `const char* const` is not of an "integral type":

```
struct T
{
   static const char* const str = "hi";
   // ^ error: 'constexpr' needed for in-class initialization of
   // static data member 'const char* const T::str' of non-integral type
};
```

but it *is* of a "literal type"; the upshot for you is that if you write it like this:

```
static constexpr const char* const xml_ID_TAG = "id";
//     ^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^
```

you should be okay. (Note that [you will still need to define it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51051942/560648), [until C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45183324/560648).)

This probably makes more sense anyway: why would you want to change the pointer?

Comment: Nope, I tried the last solution (static constexpr const char * const foo="foo") and it gives me link errors in some cases if I don't define it.

Comment: @galinette Yeah [you still need to define it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51051942/560648) (though not since C++17!). Thanks, will clarify.

Answer (score 5):

Because string literals (eg `"id"`) are stored per file compilation unit.  So if they are in a header file, there's a different instance stored for each source file that includes it.  So your 'initialisation' is trying to store different values in a `static` variable for each compilation unit that `#include`s it..

Answer (score 4):

"*Since it's [...] const*" - Nope.

You need `const char* const` - assuming you're using C++11.

Otherwise you have to put the definition in the cpp file.

See: [How to initialize a static const member in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531060/how-to-initialize-a-static-const-member-in-c)