# constexpr defining static data member of literal type that is declared const

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17

I  have a question about constexpr defining a static data member of literal type that is declared const (and not specified inline or constexpr) in the class definition:

// S.h

```
struct S
{
  static int const i; // not specified inline or constexpr
};
```

// S.cpp

```
#include "S.h"
constexpr int const S::i = 42; // definition, not declaration
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "S.h"
int main()
{
  return S::i;
}
```

Clang/gcc return 42 in C++11/14 mode, but report an error (undefined reference to S::i) in C++17 mode. If I comment out constexpr both return 42 in C++17 mode, too.

S::i has external linkage because S has external linkage. S::i is not declared constexpr and so (if I'm not mistaken) C++17 10.1.5 p1 does not apply:

> A function or static data member declared with the constexpr
>   specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable

I understand this sentence as if it means (bold my understanding):
A static data member declared with the constexpr specifier **in the class definition** is implicitly an inline variable

S::i is thus not an inline variable.
Yet the definition of S::i seems to have internal linkage in C++17 mode as if constexpr means inline. Is this correct? If so where is the proof in the standard?

Or do I misunderstand 10.1.5 p1 and it really means (bold my misunderstanding):
A static data member declared with the constexpr specifier **in the class definition and the definition in namespace scope** is implicitly an inline variable?

Answer (score 2):

[[dcl.inline]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.inline) states:

> If a function or variable with external linkage is declared inline in
>   one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation
>   units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required.

So as you pointed out, *if* we can show that `constexpr` implicitly implies `inline`, it would explain the undefined reference error of your example.

[[dcl.constexpr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr) states [emphasis mine]:

> The constexpr specifier shall be applied **only to the definition** of
>   a variable or variable template or the declaration of a function or
>   function template.

As well as:

> A function or static data member declared with the constexpr specifier
>   is implicitly an inline function or variable ([[dcl.inline]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.inline)).

[[basic.def]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def) states [emphasis mine]:

> A declaration may introduce one or more names into a translation unit
>   **or redeclare names introduced by previous declarations**.

as well as (/2):

> A declaration is a definition unless:
>
> [... none applies for `constexpr int const S::i = 42;`]

The essence here being that definitions *are declarations* (that fully define the entity introduced by the declaration), so `constexpr int const S::i = 42;` is also (in addition to being a definition) a (re-)declaration, in which case [dcl.constexpr]/1 applies, and `S::i` is inline in the translation unit of `S.cpp`, ergo, by [dcl.inline]/6, in all other translations units in which it appears. Conversely, by [dcl.constexpr]/1, the `constexpr` specifier, e.g. specifically in this context of static data members, can only appear in declarations that are definitions.

Somewhat relevant in the context of the latter is that a `constexpr` static data member declaration with initialization is, also, as of C++17, a definition, allowing for the specification that `constexpr` shall only be applied to the variable definition (i.e., never to a non-initializing declaration). See [[depr.static_constexpr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/depr.static_constexpr).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It means I could answer my own question: yes, I misunderstand 10.1.5 p1 s2. But two things bother me. First, the standards committee introduces a new language feature (inline variables) that breaks existing code that is at most 6 years old. And second, it is inconsistent with variables declared extern. Suppose in S.h there is instead "extern int const i;", in S.cpp there is instead "constexpr int const i = 42;" and in main() there is instead "return i;". This is OK, there is no undefined reference to i. The same applies to variable templates declared extern. Weird.

Comment: @xy I agree that breaking changes are always delicate. As for the your second comment, I don't see any inconsistency/weirdness there. `extern` in that context is just storage class specifier not applicable to class members (see [[dcl.stc]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.stc). By [[basic.link]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.link) `i` in `S.h` has external linkage, and for this non-class member variable, the `constexpr` does not (implicitly) imply  `inline`, thus there is no inconsistency and the external linkage of `i`, as expected, allows it to be used in `main()`.

Comment: But you mention exactly the inconsistency I mean: "the constexpr does not (implicitly) imply inline". Why does the constexpr specifier imply inline in the definition of a const static data member in namespace scope when the constexpr specifier does not imply inline in the definition of a const variable declared extern in namespace scope? S::i is actually only a class scope bound ordinary namespace scope "extern int const i". Apart from that I don't see any difference between those two. That's why I think constexpr should not imply inline for S::i.

Comment: @xy I answered your comment interpreting _"inconsistency"_ as in the _"ambiguous"_ sense (no ambiguity here), whereas I realize you refer to inconsistencies in intent between the well-defined rules for separated (although similar) entities. As for the latter, I do see your point, but I can't answer as to why the standard chose this approach (only that the examples above are, indeed, acting as well-defined and according to the standard). For such a question, you're probably better of asking it in a mail group/slack (cpplang) that is closer to those actually working with & writing the standard.

Comment: @xy [N4424](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4424.pdf) and its update/addendum [P0386R0](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r0.pdf) should give you the reasons as to _why_. The latter also introduces the `inline` implied by `constexpr` rule (in the context discussed in this Q&A), and one can speculate it has been added to avoid constructs such as `static inline constexpr const ... = ...` (as used in the former). Finally, [N4147](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4147.pdf) should also be of interest.

Comment: @xy peculiarly, the described modification _"The `constexpr` specifier implies `inline` for variables as well as functions"_ from P0386R0, specified to be applied onto (7.1.5p1) as _"A function **or variable declared with the constexpr specifier** is implicitly an `inline` function or variable ..."_, ended up (C++17 std) as limited to the subset of variables that are static data members; [dcl.constexpr]/1: _"A function or **static data member declared with the `constexpr` specifier** is implicitly an `inline` function or variable ..."_. I pinged one of SO's C++' experts for insight into this.

Comment: Specifically, the update from P0368R1 to [P0368R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf) changed the specification to not include namespace-scope variables, but I can't find any explanation as to why.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the effort to provide all this information and references. I appreciate that. Relating to the last sentence you quote: Functions declared constexpr are usually provided in header files so clients that include them could benefit from a constant expression. The same is true for static data members declared constexpr **in the class definition** because the definition is in the header file. That's why it makes sense that both are implicitly inline. In short: could _static data member declared with the constexpr specifier_ really mean **in the class definition**?

Comment: @xy No worries, I've learn stuff too. As for your quest.: I would believe that is means exactly what it says: _"static **data member** declared with the constexpr specifier"_; ergo in the class definition (most common use case, I would guess, e.g. `struct Foo { static constexpr int foo = 42; };`) **or**, as shown by this Q&A, a re-declaration (that is also a definition) e.g. in a separate `.cpp` file. If they had stated it, explicitly, as _"... in the class definition"_, I believe this would exclude e.g. the use case you show above (class definition in header but `constexpr` re-def. in .cpp).

Comment: I don't know if I understand you right, but if it means "in the class definition" then my use case from above would **not** be excluded, but instead it would work just as it does in C++11/14 mode. That is actually my intention why I posted this question!

Comment: @xy Maybe my last comment was a bit messy, I'll try to clarify: I don't see it meaning explicitly _"in the class definition"_: the `constexpr` specifier **may** be in the class definition, but may also be elsewhere (as you've shown in your example). Standard only mentions that the section we've discussed (P0368R2 addition) applies to static data members (no other variables), but there is no constraint on **where/in which (re-)declaration** the `constexpr` specifier **may** appear. It can appear in the class definition, or in an out-of-class (re-)declaration (that is also a definition).

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree, of course. `constexpr` can appear in the class definition **or** in the definition at namespace scope (if it wasn't already declared `constexpr` in the class definition). Eventually that's why it compiles in C++11/14 mode. I never said that it could be specified **only** in the class definition. I just say that I think that **if** it is specified in the class definition then it is implicitly inline, otherwise (if it is specified at namespace scope) it is **not** implicitly inline and hence not an inline variable. Or do we misunderstand each other?

Comment: @xy Thanks for your clarification, I think we follow each other now, but our thoughts differ as follows: my understanding is that **if** it is declared `constexpr` (in class definition **or** elsewhere), then it is `inline` (so this differs from what you state in your last clause above), in which case it is `inline` in all translation units. So in you example, `S::i` is implicitly `inline` even though the `constexpr` does not appear in the class definition.

Comment: (in your example it is, implicitly `inline`, but simply by including `S.h` into a translation unit other than the one using `S.cpp`, _will not include a definition of it_, since the definition is present only in `S.cpp`. From [dcl.inline]/6: _"An inline function or variable shall be **defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used** and shall have exactly the same definition in every case ([basic.def.odr])"_. It's now my strongest subject, but I believe `S::i` is odr-used in the translation unit of `main.cpp`? Since it is `inline`, it then needs to be defined also in this TU).

Comment: Yes, we differ only in the question whether or not `S::i` is implicitly inline in `S.cpp`. You say yes, I say no. As for your question: as far as I understand that concept `S::i` is **not** odr-used in `main.cpp` because neither its address nor reference is taken.

Comment: @xy At least we've found consensus over what we disagree over! :) Adding `constexpr int Foo::bar = 42;` to `main.cpp` in you example makes it compile fine for C++17, whereas it will break it for C++11/14 (_"multiple definition of `S::i`_). I believe this sufficiently supports my view, that `S::i` is indeed implicitly set to `inline` via its definition (redeclaration) in `S.cpp`. The error for C++11/14 (where it's not `inline`) also supports that it should be odr-used in `main.cpp`, which would close the loop of my argument (I'll dig into the standard to see what exception it fulfills for odr).

Comment: @xy I believe that [basic.def.odr]/3(https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr) will make `S::i` odr-used, as long as `main.cpp` _only sees the declaration in `S.h`_ (because this does not include `constexpr`!). However, possibly, when we add a definition of `S::i` to `main.cpp`, it is no longer odr-used (in your example), by [basic.def.odr]/3. It is, however, from `S.cpp`, implicitly `inline`.

Comment: I try to answer your question from above. A constexpr static data member defined in the class definition in a header file is technically 'inline' since C++11 because _it can be included multiple times by source files yet there's implicitly only one definition_. It behaves like an inline variable, so it makes sense it's now implicitly inline. But a constexpr variable defined at namespace scope in a header file is _defined in every source file that includes it_ because a const declared variable has internal linkage. It behaves not like an inline variable, hence it's not implicitly inline.

Comment: @xy (Pardon the late response) I actually can't favour one or the other theories here over the other, any longer, but would really like to see what someone working closer with the standard would say. Thanks for the discussion!

Answer (score 0):

> Yet the definition of S::i seems to have internal linkage in C++17
>   mode as if constexpr means inline. Is this correct? If so where is the
>   proof in the standard?

Yes, it is correct. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) :

> The inline specifier, when used in a decl-specifier-seq of a variable
>   with static storage duration (static class member or namespace-scope
>   variable), declares the variable to be an inline variable.
>
> **A static member variable (but not a namespace-scope variable) declared constexpr is implicitly an inline variable.** **(since C++17)**

Comment: The last (bold) sentence reflects 10.1.5 p1 s2. And as far as I understand the wording "declared constexpr"  the static data member must be declared constexpr **in the class definition** which is not the case here. That's why I wrote that I think that sentence does not apply here.
In other words: does the constexpr definition in S.cpp mean that S::i is declared constexpr although it is not declared constexpr in the class definition?