# Undefined reference to static const member

Tags: c++, static-members, undefined-reference

This problem of mine was reproduced on cpp.sh with C++14 activated (I don't know if that is relevant...)

I have this program:

```
// Example program 1
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Constants
{
  public:
    static const int64_t constant_1 = -123;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int64_t> vec;
  vec.push_back(static_cast<int64_t>(Constants::constant_1));
  std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
1
```

Now I try to remove the `static_cast`. This gives me this program:

```
// Example program 2
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Constants
{
  public:
    static const int64_t constant_1 = -123;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int64_t> vec;
  vec.push_back(Constants::constant_1);
  std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
/tmp/cceayEj1.o: In function `main':
:(.text.startup+0x2): undefined reference to `Constants::constant_1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My understanding is that it is ok to initialize static members in the class declaration ([How to initialize a static const member in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531060/how-to-initialize-a-static-const-member-in-c)) so I guess this is not related to initialization.

Why do I have to `static_cast` in my exampel program?