# Initialize static const member of a class, where the member is of a private type?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

```
// gamewindow.hpp

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

class GameWindow : public sf::RenderWindow
{
public:
    GameWindow(const uint32_t&, const uint32_t&, const std::string&);
    void toggleFullscreen();

    static const ResolutionSetting w640h480,
                                   w1600h900,
                                   w1920h1080,
                                   w2560h1440;
private:
    class ResolutionSetting
    {
    public:
        ResolutionSetting(const uint32_t& width, const uint32_t& height)
        : res(width, height) {}
    private:
        sf::Vector2u res;
    };

    std::string _title;
    uint32_t _width;
    uint32_t _height;
};
```

I am attempting to initialize the public `ResolutionSetting` objects within the `GameWindow` class, where the `ResolutionSetting` class is defined to be a `private` class within `GameWindow`.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531105/4562156) post which details how to initialize `static` `const` members of classes, however this doesn't include the case when the type definition of said member is inaccessible from outside class scope (such as when the type is specified with `private` access rules).

And how do I go about initializing these objects? Would:

```
const GameWindow::ResolutionSetting GameWindow::w640h480(640, 480);
```

or

```
const GameWindow::ResolutionSetting GameWindow::w640h480 = GameWindow::ResolutionSetting(640, 480);
```

suffice? (assuming I can correct any possible issues with `ResolutionSetting` being inaccessible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> suffice? (assuming I can correct any possible issues with ResolutionSetting being inaccessible).

Yes suffice. `GameWindow::ResolutionSetting` is accessible in the initializer expression of the static member.

So you can define them as:

```
const GameWindow::ResolutionSetting GameWindow::w640h480(640, 480);
const GameWindow::ResolutionSetting GameWindow::w1600h900{1600, 900};
const GameWindow::ResolutionSetting GameWindow::w1920h1080 = GameWindow::ResolutionSetting(1920, 1080);
```

From the standard, [$12.2.3.2/2 Static data members [class.static.data]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.data#2):

> The initializer expression in the definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class ([basic.scope.class]).

[Minimal sample](http://rextester.com/PYSWRN83000)