# G++ (C++14) linker error on working C++03 code

Tags: c++, static, g++, linker-errors

Consider the following piece of code.

```
class aClass
{
public:
    static const int HALLO = -3;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<double > a;
  std::vector<int> b;
  std::vector<int> c;
  int d = aClass::HALLO; //fine
  a.resize(10,aClass::HALLO); //fine
  b.resize(10,aClass::HALLO); // linker error c++11 and c++14
  c.resize(10,(int)(double)aClass::HALLO); //fine
  std::cout<<a[0]<<endl;
  std::cout<<b[0]<<endl;
  std::cout<<c[0]<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling works with C++03 and yields the output:

```
-3
-3
-3
```

Compiling with C++11 or C++14, however, leads to a linker error:

```
/tmp/cc3BARzY.o: In Funktion `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x66): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `aClass::HALLO'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Weirdly enough, this only happens for vector `b`. If there is a cast to double(`a`) or even to double and back to int (`c`), the code runs as expected.

How can this behaviour be explained?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member.  I'm trying to find a target that talks about ODR though.

Comment: I wonder that `class aClass
{
public:
    static const int HALLO = -3;
};` compiled with C++03. (I didn't know this.) However, I fixed this (and other issues) of your MCVE: [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fb8f3fcbaf23ab6)

Comment: @Scheff : Pre-C++11, _only_ static data members of const integral type were possible to initialize inline; C++11 relaxed this restriction to allow more types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until C++11 the signature of `std::vector::resize()` was

```
void resize( size_type count, T value = T() );
```

Now it is instead

```
void resize( size_type count, T const& value );
```

The change from pass-by-value to pass-by-const-ref causes the callsite to [ODR-use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19630570/636019) `aClass::HALLO` where previously it did not. Casting to `double` then back to `int` yields a temporary in a way that avoids ODR-use; the call to `a.resize()` works for the same reason, as the `int` value is implicitly cast to a `double` and the argument reference is bound to the resulting temporary.

The usual fix here is to [provide a definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3531060/636019) for `aClass::HALLO`; if for some reason that's undesirable for you, a shorthand for yielding a temporary to avoid ODR-use is to apply unary `operator+`:

```
b.resize(10, +aClass::HALLO);
```

Comment: ... which is done by adding `const int aClass::HALLO;` in the program.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for! Since I like both answers equally,  I accepted the one from the user with less reputation.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it works for `double` vector, but not `int` is funny. The signature for `std::vector::resize` is `void resize(size_type count, const value_type& value )` since C++11. Taking a reference to the object makes it ODR-used, and because of that, your static `int` member now needs to be defined somewhere in your application.

However, when you `std::vector<double>`, you can't bind a reference to the object. Instead, compiler creates a temporary `double` object and bind the reference to said temporary. Because of that, you avoid ODR-using the static member of the class, as creating a `double` temporary doesn't ODR-use it, and ODR-using temporary is fine.

Fixing the issue is trivial if you have .cpp file for the class, in which case you simply define your static there. However, for header-only class the solution is not trivial until C++17, where you can have inline variables and have a very nice solution:

```
#include <vector>

class aClass
{
public:
    static const int HALLO;
};

inline const int aClass::HALLO = -3;

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> b;
  b.resize(10,aClass::HALLO); //fine

  return 0;
}
```