# How to implement static class members in a header-only library?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am implementing a new header-only Library in VS2019, targeting C++11. As discussed ([How to initialize a static const member in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531060/how-to-initialize-a-static-const-member-in-c)) you cannot initialize a non-int static class member in-line.

```
class A {
private:
  static const std::string SPECIAL_KEY = "A8787HHH"; //NOT OK
  /*...*/
};
```

Instead you have to define it outside the class, typically in a CPP file:

```
class A {
private:
  static const std::string SPECIAL_KEY;
  /*...*/
};

const std::string A::SPECIAL_KEY = "A8787HHH";
```

But in a header-only library this runs into problems. I tried to do the above all in the same header and it worked in a simple test-app, but in real use I got linker errors that symbol A::SPECIAL_KEY was multiply defined, not surprising really as the header will get included in multiple places ([How to initialize private static members in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/how-to-initialize-private-static-members-in-c))

In C++17 you *can* define in-line (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062055/197229) but that's not any help to me on this code-base. C++ doesn't provide static class constructors either.

Header-only libraries have become quite widely used so is there a standard workaround to what must be a common sort of problem, until such time as we might be able to upgrade to C++17?