# static const member variable initialization

Tags: c++, class, static-members

Looks like I can init a POD static const member, but not other types:

```
struct C {
  static const int a = 42;      // OK
  static const string b = "hi"; // compile error
};
```

Why?

Comment: I bet someone will answer with a quote from the standard, which doesn't really tell you *why* :-)

Comment: I avoided the standard.

Comment: T think it's because it hase to be evaluatet at compile-time. Thats why it also works with constexpr in C++11

Comment: @Bathsheba And you're also attempting to explain *why*, which is good.

Comment: @juanchopanza: it's not a full answer though; by no means the whole story. I might tin it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ where to initialize static const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605520/c-where-to-initialize-static-const)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax `initializer in the class definition` is only allowed with integral and enum types. For `std::string`, it must be defined outside the class definition and initialized there.

```
struct C {
  static const int a = 42;     
  static const string b; 
};

const string C::b = "hi"; // in one of the .cpp files
```

`static members` must be defined in one translation unit to fulfil the one definition rule. If C++ allows the definition below;

```
struct C {
  static const string b = "hi"; 
};
```

`b` would be defined in each translation unit that includes the header file.

C++ only allows to define `const static` data members of `integral` or `enumeration` type in the class declaration as a short-cut. The reason why `const static` data members of other types cannot be defined is that non-trivial initialization would be required (constructor needs to be called).

Comment: But the question is, why?

Answer (score 6):

`string` is not a primitive type (like `int`) but is a class.

Disallowing this is sensible; the initialisation of `static`s happens before `main`. And constructors can invoke all sorts of functions that might not be available on initialisation.

Comment: that means `static const char* string = "hi";` should work, right?

Comment: So why is it possible to initialize static locals in a function at the moment the function is called?

Comment: That's not true- you can initialize constants at other scopes like this. It also doesn't explain other primitives like `const char*`.

Comment: "Constructors can invoke all sorts of functions that might not be available on initialization"? This implies that global objects (i.e., global non-primitive variables) should also be disallowed (which, as you know, is not the case).

Answer (score 5):

I'll sum up the rules about direct class initialization on C++98 vs C++11:

The following code is illegal in C++03, but works just as you expect in C++11. In C++11, you can think of it as the initializers being injected into each of the constructors of POD, unless that constructor sets another value.

```
struct POD {
    int integer = 42; 
    float floating_point = 4.5f;
    std::string character_string = "Hello";
};
```

Making the fields mutable static members will break the code in both standards, this is because the `static` guarantees there to be only one copy of the variable and thus we have to declare the members in a exactly one file, just like we would do with global variables using the referred using the extern keyword.

```
// This does not work
struct POD {
    static int integer = 42;
    static float floating_point = 4.5f;
    static std::string character_string = "Hello";
};

int   POD::integer = 42;
float POD::floating_point = 4.5f;
std::string POD::character_string = "Hello";

// This works
struct POD {
    static int integer;
    static float floating_point;
    static std::string character_string;
};

int   POD::integer = 42;
float POD::floating_point = 4.3f;
std::string POD::character_string = "hello";
```

If we try to make them, const static members a new array of rules arise:

```
struct POD {
    static const int integer = 42;               // Always works
    static constexpr float floating_point = 4.5f;    // Works in C++11 only.
    static const std::string character_string = "Hello"; // Does not work.
    constexpr static const std::string character_string = "Hello"; // Does not work (last checked in C++11)

    // Like some others have also mentioned, this works.
    static const std::string character_string;
};

// In a sourcefile:
const std::string POD::character_string = "Hello";
```

So, from C++11 onwards, it is allowed to make static constants of non-integer trivial types variable. Strings unfortunately does not fit the bill, therefore we cannot initialize constexpr std::strings even in C++11.

All is not lost though, as an answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858141/conveniently-declaring-compile-time-strings-in-c) mentions, you could create a string class functions as a string literal.

NB! Note that you this is metaprogramming at its best, if the object is declared as constexpr static inside a class, then, as soon as you enter run-time, the object is nowhere to be found. I haven't figured out why, please feel free to comment on it.

```
// literal string class, adapted from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr
class conststr {
    const char * p;
    std::size_t sz; 
    public:
    template<std::size_t N>
        constexpr conststr(const char(&a)[N]) : p(a), sz(N-1) {}
    // constexpr functions signal errors by throwing exceptions from operator ?:
    constexpr char operator[](std::size_t n) const {
        return n < sz ? p[n] : throw std::out_of_range("");
    }   
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return sz; }

    constexpr bool operator==(conststr rhs) {
        return compare(rhs) == 0;
    }   

    constexpr int compare(conststr rhs, int pos = 0) {
        return ( this->size() < rhs.size() ? -1 :
                    ( this->size() > rhs.size() ? 1 : 
                        ( pos == this->size()  ? 0 : 
                            ( (*this)[pos] < rhs[pos] ? -1 :
                                ( (*this)[pos] > rhs[pos] ? 1 : 
                                    compare(rhs, pos+1)
                                )   
                            )   
                        )   
                    )   
                );  
    }   

    constexpr const char * c_str() const { return p; }
};
```

Now you can declare a conststr directly in you class:

```
struct POD {
    static const int integer = 42;               // Always works
    static constexpr float floating_point = 4.5f;          // Works in C++11 only.
    static constexpr conststr character_string = "Hello"; // C++11 only, must be declared.
};  



int main() {
    POD pod; 

    // Demonstrating properties.
    constexpr conststr val = "Hello";
    static_assert(val == "Hello", "Ok, you don't see this.");
    static_assert(POD::character_string == val, "Ok");
    //static_assert(POD::character_string == "Hi", "Not ok.");
    //static_assert(POD::character_string == "hello", "Not ok.");

    constexpr int compare = val.compare("Hello");
    cout << compare << endl;

    const char * ch = val.c_str(); // OK, val.c_str() is substituted at compile time.
    cout << ch << endl;   // OK

    cout << val.c_str() << endl; // Ok

    // Now a tricky one, I haven't figured out why this one does not work:
    // cout << POD::character_string.c_str() << endl; // This fails linking.

    // This works just fine.
    constexpr conststr temp = POD::character_string;
    cout << temp.c_str() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++17 :

If you can use `static constexpr` you will have the desired result, but if you cant : use the `inline variable` introduce by C++17.

In your case, since `std::string` does not have a `constexpr` constructor, the solution is `inline static const std::string`

Example :

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() { return 4;}

struct Demo
{
   inline static const int i = foo();  
   inline static const std::string str = "info";  

    
};
int main() {
    std::cout << Demo::i << " " << Demo::str<< std::endl;
    
}
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ft2lpz3QMBAhgrFs)