# initialize a static const std::pair<string,vector<string>>

Tags: c++, initialization, stdvector, composite, std-pair

I have a

```
class myclass
{
    // ...
    static const vector<pair<string,vector<string>>> var;
    // ...
};
```

in the class definition, to use mappings of single strings to several others. I am using vector<> instead of arrays, in order to be able to add mapping pairs and mapping lengths without having to mantain size variables as well. Is there a way to initialize the variable in the corresponding .cpp file like a vector of a non composite type, that is, in the format:

```
 const vector<pair<string,vector<string>>> myclass :: var =
{
   ???
}
```

or do I have to use a static method, like

```
static myclass::initStaticMembers(){...}
```

If there is a way to do it in the 1st way, what is the syntax?
I have searched, but did not find the syntax to do the composite std::pair initialization. For example, you can init a `vector<string>` with

```
vector <string>myvec={"elem1", "elem2","elem3"};
```

but how do you init the complex `vector<pair<string,vector<string>>>` ?
Thank you.

Comment: This has been asked many times. y u no search?

Comment: Yes, there is. Why don't you make use of it then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ where to initialize static const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605520/c-where-to-initialize-static-const)

Comment: I have searched, but did not find the syntax to do the composite std::pair initialization. For example, you can init a vector<string> with
`vector<string> myvec={"elem1", "elem2","elem3"};` , but how do you init the complex `vector<pair<string,vector<string>>>` ?

Will update original post with this comment.

Comment: @npit Curly braces initialization can be nested. Try something like `{ {"pair1", {"element11", "element12"}}, {"pair2", {"element21", "element22"}} }`

Comment: @VictorPolevoy thanks for the link, but I know where I should initialize it, my question is what is the syntax to do it, if it is possible to be done without an initializer function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple as always - just logically nest each entity with it's initializer list and with use of implicit conversions. For example, I've worked with your code a bit and made this example:

```
class A {
    static const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>> var;
};

const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>> A::var = {
    {"abc", {"def", "ghj"}}
};
```

Just when you write initialization with initiliazer lists think about each entity from left to right in the template:

1. `std::vector` = needs `{ELEM}`. Result is `{ELEM}`.
2. Inside `std::vector` - an `std::pair` which also needs `{FIRST, SECOND}`. Result is `{{FIRST, SECOND}}`.
   .. and so on.

So, imagine it like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>>
     ^      ^         ^            ^           ^        ^
     |      |         |            |           |        |

     {      {         "abc"        {           "abc", "def"  }  }   }

     |      |                      |                         |  |   |
     |      |                      |--------vector-----------|  |   |
     |      |--------------------------pair---------------------|   |
     |---------------------------vector-----------------------------|
```

Comment: Thank you Victor, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest the initializations

```
const std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::vector<std::string>>> Foo::var = 
{ // start of vector
    { "pair1", {"one", "two"}},
    { "pair2", {"three", "four"}},
    { "pair3", {"five", "six"}}
};// end of vector
```

Then you could do something like:

```
class Foo  // this would be in the .h file
{
public:
    static const std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::vector<std::string>>> var;
};

// this part would be in the .cpp file
const std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::vector<std::string>>> Foo::var = 
{ // start of vector
    { "pair1", {"one", "two"}},
    { "pair2", {"three", "four"}},
    { "pair3", {"five", "six"}}
};// end of vector

int main()
{
    for (const auto & p : Foo::var)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << "\t";
        for (const auto & e : p.second)
        {
            std::cout << e << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
pair1   one two 
pair2   three   four    
pair3   five    six
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baba706fca64b10e)</kbd>