# In C++ How to access value of static local variable between class methods

Tags: c++

How do I meet below objective in C++ language.
My objective is to have an input source (a structure) defined in a constructor (or another method of same class) and access it in another method for processing.
For Eg:

```
#include "iostream"
class A
{ 
  public: 
      struct source{     //input source
        char* input;
        unsigned int result;
      };

      A(); //constructor
      ~A(); //destructor
      void process();
};

A::A()
{
  //static local input source
  static const source inp[2] = { {"input1", 2}, {"input2", 3} };
}

void A::process()
{
//The value of static structure "inp" initialized in constructor is to be 
//  read here. 
// Say I want to print the "result"
  std::cout << "input1 result" << inp[0].result; //should print 2
  std::cout << "input2 result" << inp[1].result; //should print 3
}
```

Any alternate approach meeting above objective is most welcome.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: In short, you cannot.

Comment: This seems quite silly. Why not have a normal, stateful class?

Comment: Make inp a class member instead of putting it in the constructor. Members can be static const.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best approach is to make the static constant variable a public member of the class, and then access it normally. See this post for more info:

[C++ where to initialize static const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605520/c-where-to-initialize-static-const)

Comment: How can this static variable be initialized with an initialization list as in the Jaydeep's questions? Could you provide a working example in your answer?

Comment: I thought C++11 has no problem with that @cassandradied

Comment: And is there a working example? I have tried your approach and it does not work in my conditions.

Comment: What do you mean by ["working example"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization)?

Comment: By “working example” I assume a piece of code that works in given conditions for sure, compiled and tested.