# C++ : Undefined reference in Map::insert

Tags: c++, qt

Somewhere in a .h file:

```
namespace gpBenchAPI {
 struct AbstractConsts {
  public:
    static const uint8_t STATUS_TAG_NOT_FOUND = 2;
 }; //AbstractConsts
}
```

Somewhere in another .h file:

```
class MyClass{
private:
     void method();
     QMap<uint8_t, QString> errorCodes;
};
```

Somewhere in a .cpp file:

```
   void MyClass::method(){
       using namespace gpBenchAPI;
       errorCodes.insert(AbstractConsts::STATUS_TAG_NOT_FOUND, "A-1");
   }
```

This code is rising a linking error:

```
  undefined reference to `gpBenchAPI::AbstractConsts::STATUS_TAG_NOT_FOUND'
```

but this code compiles and links:

```
 switch (status) {
    case AbstractConsts::STATUS_TAG_HUNTING:
        return 0;
  }
```

If I do :

```
 errorCodes.insert(2, "A-1");
```

no problem. Why?

Added: 
If, **like in the suggested dupplicated question's answer**, I initialize the const in a cpp file like this:

```
const uint8_t AbstractConsts::STATUS_TAG_NOT_FOUND = 2;
```

and remove the initialization from the .h file, the "switch" does not compile anymore:

```
The value of 'gpBenchAPI::AbstractConsts::STATUS_TAG_NOT_FOUND' is not usable in a constant expression
     case AbstractConsts::STATUS_TAG_NOT_FOUND:
                          ^
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605520/c-where-to-initialize-static-const read the small print in the most voted answer

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi, added some info, taking into account the most voted answer.

Comment: Why do not you use an enum instead of a static?

Comment: As Allessandro implies, if you read the comment to the top answer, you need to *define* the variable in the .cpp **but not initialize it there** (leave the initialization in the header).

Comment: @MartinBonner : right !

Comment: @eyllanesc: In this case, I will because it makes  sense but sometimes not and I wanted to know why.